# Strange horizontal striations when connecting a monitor through thunderbolt dock

Tags: laptop, display, lenovo-laptop, docking-station

Has anyone seen these horizontal striations on a monitor before? I'm connecting a Lenovo Legion 5 Pro to an LG GN850-B via a Dell WD19TB Docking Station.

The monitor looks just fine when connected directly to the laptop (DP to USB-C), but when I add the dock in the middle (Monitor DP to Dock DP to Laptop USB-C) it starts to look like this: https://i.imgur.com/x3h9Ezf.jpg

The monitor also looks just fine when connecting other devices via the thunderbolt dock, e.g. a Macbook pro or another Windows laptop or a Chromebook, so it feels like it must be something specific to the relationship between the Lenovo Legion 5 and the thunderbolt dock. I've tried changing the refresh rates of both the laptop and the monitor, but I'm just at a loss at this point.

Comment: Could be an issue with the refresh rate being too high. Can you change it down to 60Hz and then go up from there?

Answer (score 0):

D'oh it's because the Lenovo Legion 5 Pro I'm using has an AMD CPU and it doesn't support Thunderbolt. I can still use the dock to connect peripherals, but I doubt it's possible to get monitor working.